# applications of topological spaces that are $T_1$, but are not $T_2$

Tags: general-topology, soft-question, separation-axioms

If a topological space is $T_1$, its specialization preorder is the equality (so it is trivial). If a topological space is $T_2$ (Hausdorff), a limit of a proper filter is unique. I suppose this is why topological spaces studied in analysis are $T_2$. It seems to me there is a gap between $T_1$ and $T_2$ axioms. Are there any interesting applications of topological spaces that are $T_1$, but are not $T_2$?

Comment: Just out of curiosity (for my own education), a space is $T_1$ if every point of the space is closed as a set. Is that the definition? And what do you mean by a "specialization preorder"? Would you explain that please?

Comment: @stressed-out $x \le y$ iff $x \in \overline{\{y\}}$ is the specialisation order. So for $T_1$ spaces this implies $x=y$. In $T_0$ spaces this need not hold, but there we do have that ($x \le y) \land (y \le x) \implies x=y$, so it's an actual poset.